# help with regex match

Tags: php, regex

i want to retrieve following urls with a regex:

```
 HREF="http://www.getty.edu/vow/TGNFullDisplay?find=&place=&nation=&english=Y&subjectid=7009830"

 HREF="http://www.getty.edu/vow/TGNFullDisplay?find=&place=&nation=&english=Y&subjectid=7009830&ptype=PF"
```

the difference is the ending. the first one omits the &ptype=PF and the last one includes it.

at the moment im using this pattern:

```
 protected $uriPattern = '/http:\/\/www\.getty\.edu\/vow\/.*?\?find=&place=&nation=&english=Y&subjectid=......./i';
```

but that works only for the first one.

i wonder how the regex pattern would look like for the preg_match_all to match both of them. thanks for help.

Comment: Related: [PHP preg_replace making regex optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3704737/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an optional part in the strings you are matching, you can add `(optional)?`, in your case `(&ptype=PF)?`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected $uriPattern = '/http:\/\/www\.getty\.edu\/vow\/.*?\?find=&place=&nation=&english=Y&subjectid=.......(&ptype=PF){0,1}/i';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest the more succinct

`"/http://www\.getty\.edu/vow/TGNFullDisplay\?find=&place=&nation=&english=Y&subjectid=.+(&ptype=PF)?/i"`

The forward slashes are not special in either PHP nor RegEx, and thus do not need to be escaped, and the ID could be a different length.

Comment: i thought that too..but i dont get why using .+ wont work! i tried .+?, (.)+?, (,)+ too but it doesnt work.

Comment: how about using a (reasonable) range for the ID then: `subjectid=[0-9]{1,10}`