# PHP preg_replace making regex optional?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-replace

I have some content that I am trying to parse...

I have html and with in the html I want to replace all my img tags with a custom string. Now one of the problems I have is that some content that comes in: the image tags is between a anchor.

ex.

```
<a href="link"><img></a>
```

The following code I have works...but I want it to be optional so in case no anchor tag is surrounded by a img tag does anyone have any good resource on regex or could help me out?

Thank you!

```
$content = preg_replace('#<a.*?>'.$image_tag.'</a>#i', "{$image_id}", $content);
```

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, therefore not suitable for regular expressions. Use a DOM/HTML Parser. They're simple to use.

Comment: Not again... SO really should set up an auto responder for regex-for-html-parsing questions.

Comment: We can't really demonstrate how to use a parser when the [mcve] is incomplete / lacking detail.

Answer (score 4):

- A question mark after a token makes that token optional.
- Use `(?...)` to group several tokens (without creating a capturing group).
- Combining these, `(?...)?` makes the group optional.

So you can do this:

```
$content = preg_replace('#(?:<a.*?>)?'.$image_tag.'(?:</a>)?#i',
                        "{$image_id}",
                        $content);
```

You might also want to look at alternative solutions that are not based on regular expressions, such as using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason

```
$content = preg_replace('#'.$image_tag.'#i', "{$image_id}", $content);
```

wouldn't work?  If you don't have the ^ and $ anchors on your regular expression, it should just search for **$image_tag** anywhere in the data whether or not it's surrounded by the <a> tags.  If that doesn't work, maybe try:

```
$content = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>)?'.$image_tag.'(</a>)?#i', "{$image_id}", $content);
```

which makes the <a> and </a> tags into subpatterns, followed by the **?** modifier (i.e. the subpattern may occur 0 or 1 times)